# Folder accessing error in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am working on a asp.net website which is created by someone else.
Some files are exist in root folder and some are exist in one sub folder.
I can access all files from root folder in the browser, however when try to access the pages from sub folder is shows following error

Access is denied.
Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

I unable to point out the issue. I checked the web.config file, but didnt get anything related to that folder. I know it is difficult to find the exact issue in my case, but I would appreciate if anyone can give me possible reasons or clues so that i can try.

Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT**
There is a sub folder web.config with the following content

However, even if I login with "administrator" it fails.

I got the issue, actually previously it was Forms authentication which I commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a web.config file in the sub-folder? These can apply local restrictions.

Other questions that it would be good to know the answer to:

What authentication scheme (forms, windows etc) are you using?

What sort of content are you trying to access (static content or aspx)

what version of IIS are you using?

Comment: I see, web.config file in exist in the sub folder also like this <authorization >
        <allow users="administrator"/>
        <deny users="*" />        
      </authorization>

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ACL problem to me. More information, as Xhalent asks, would be useful. Does the user that IIS is using have access to all of the files on the file system?

Comment: Yes, there is no restriction in IIS, because I copied the files in to the new system